# Unable to reduce the size of the input field (form.control) with floating label in react in using react-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to reduce the height of the input field (form control). I am using floating labels with the form controls. I am using react-bootstrap with react. I have tried to reduce the size using the `size="sm"` and I have also the `className="Input-sm"`. I have also added `className="input-sm"` to the Form.Control based on the answer posted below. However I am not able to reduce the size of the input field.

I am using the default input field from the react-bootstrap. I am not trying to reduce the size of the floating label text. I am not trying to reduce the width of the input field Form.Control.

Below is the code for the input field( Form Control)

```
<FloatingLabel
    controlId="floatingInput"
    label="Last name"
    className="mb-3"
    type="text"
>
    <Form.Control
    size="sm"
    type="text"
    className="Input-sm"
    placeholder="Last name"
    />
</FloatingLabel>
```

This did not work for me. What should I do to reduce the size of the input field?

Comment: In the case of floating labels, the size of the input isn't really governed by the `size` prop, or by manually adding `className='form-control-sm'`. Note that `input-sm` doesn't do anything that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of floating labels, the size of the input isn't really governed by the `size` prop, or by manually adding `className='form-control-sm'`. Note that adding a class of `input-sm` doesn't do anything that I'm aware of.

```css
.form-floating>.form-control {
    padding: 1rem 0.75rem;
}

.form-floating>.form-control, .form-floating>.form-select {
    height: calc(3.5rem + 2px);
    line-height: 1.25;
}
.form-control-sm {
    min-height: calc(1.5em + 0.5rem + 2px);
    /* padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem; Cancelled out by .form-floating */
    font-size: .875rem;
    border-radius: 0.2rem;
}
```

Having a look at what happens to the CSS if you add `.form-control-sm` looks like it only really affects the padding, and is over-ridden by the `.form-floating` class. Forcing the padding via `!important` just makes the input text alignment go to the left which looks a bit janky.

In order to make the input smaller, you'll need to experiment with the height and line-heights:

```css
.form-floating>.form-control, .form-floating>.form-select {
    height: calc(3.5rem + 2px);
    line-height: 1.25;
}
```

Comment: I have adding `form-control-sm` classsName to the Form.Control, It definetely does not reduce the size of the Form.Control.

Comment: Yes, I believe that was my point - adding `.form-control-sm` doesn't do much in this context, you'll need to play around with the height - but again, there's not much room to play with so you'll have to experiment to get it right.